# Python IF/ELIF statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Okay so for some reason `if` statement works, but `elif` doesn't.. not sure why, there's been no syntax or indentation errors, script runs fine however it doesn't use `elif` as if it wasn't written..

example of code:

```
try:
    if '120' in resp.read():
        print '120'
        self.write_to_file('120' '\n')
        return True
    elif '130' in resp.read():
        print '130'
        self.write_to_file('130' '\n')
        return True
    else:
        print 'no number'
        return False
except:
```

Comment: [f.read coming up empty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4952689/2301450)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read a *single time* and after that do the comparisons with the value that was read:

```
try:
    value = resp.read()
    if '120' in value:
        print '120'
        self.write_to_file('120' '\n')
        return True
    elif '130' in value:
        print '130'
        self.write_to_file('130' '\n')
        return True
    else:
        print 'no number'
        return False
except:
    # do something here!
    print('error')
```

Comment: Thank you that did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `resp.read()` once will read the response completely, so subsequent calls of `resp.read()` will not yield any output.

You need to store the output in a variable first, and then check on the variable instead of the response again:

```
response = resp.read()
if '120' in response:
    print '120'
    self.write_to_file('120' '\n')
    return True
elif '130' in response:
    print '130'
    self.write_to_file('130' '\n')
    return True
else:
    print 'no number'
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for your support :)